# how to not delete a single particular session variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have  a problem with deleting session variables..

Assume I have 30 session variables...I want to delete 29 session variables but one.How can I do this please help me!

I tried Session.RemoveAll() With this it deletes ALL the sessions.But my required requirement is to delete all but ONE Session.How do i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just simply save the variable you want to keep, clear all and put it back;

```
var value = Session["tokeep"]; 
Session.RemoveAll(); 
Session["tokeep"] = value;
```

Comment: I have thought it first but I though first d-allocating and then allocating is not good.

Comment: @Șhȇkhaṝ What problem would it cause? :) The value itself won't be destroyed and recreated in any way.

Comment: I think the garbage collector will have to work for d-allocating the memory and then new instance will be created. If I am not wrong.

Comment: @Șhȇkhaṝ As long as anything (the session or the `value` variable) keeps a reference to the value, the value will not be garbage collected. Some internal structure inside `Session` may be released to the garbage collector, however a `RemoveAll` is most likely also much more efficient than removing a value at a time.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Session.Remove` to remove using `key` from the session collection.

You can loop through you session collection

```
for (int i = 0; i < Session.Contents.Count; i++)
{
      var key = Session.Keys[i];
      var value = Session[i];

      //remove the key except one
      if(key!="youkey")
           Session.Remove(key);

}
```

### Edit 1

As suggested by @JoachimIsaksson

```
 for (int i = 0; i < Session.Contents.Count; i++)
 {
      var key = Session.Keys[i];
      var value = Session[i];

      //remove the key except one
      if(key!="youkey")
      {
           Session.Remove(key);
           i++;
       }

 }
```

### Edit 2

As suggested by @JoachimIsaksson I am not sure right one or not

```
 for (int i = 0; i < Session.Contents.Count; i++)
 {
      var key = Session.Keys[i];
      var value = Session[i];

      //remove the key except one
      if(key!="youkey")
      {
           Session.Remove(key);
           i--;
       }

 }
```

Comment: Hm, if you remove key `i`, won't `i+1` become `i` and be skipped the next iteration?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson that was my mistake I have update my answer. Hope this is right.

Comment: @mason Actually, no, since you're modifying the collection while iterating over it, the first version will not remove all keys. For example, if you have `[a b]` in the collection and remove index 0, you'll end up with `[b]` and continuing at position 1 which ends the loop since `Contents` only has one entry. `b` will in other words not be considered for deletion.

Comment: The problem is that removing an entry at index 2 is in no way guaranteed to not renumber the indexes of the whole collection. In other words, just backing up a position and continuing may very well skip items too.